# SKRenderer -- the mystery class

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, metal, skscene

Here I was getting all hyped about pulling off-screen Metal textures out of SpriteKit after watching the session 609 video from WWDC2017.

This was over a year ago!

And yet there are absolutely no overview docs on `SKRenderer` and there is no sample code either.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skrenderer

I find this very odd indeed.  **Does anyone here have any insight on this class, its docs or sample code?**

BTW,  the same goes for `SKTransformNode`.

Comment: There's some documentation for these two classes in the header files which declare them, for what that's worth. Always check the headers. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basic use of `SKRenderer` is pretty straightforward, but there are some oddities that make it somewhat quirky in practice.

First, the fundamentals. To instantiate a renderer, use the `rendererWithDevice:` method. This method takes a `id<MTLDevice>`, such as the system default device. Pardon the Objective-C; this will translate easily to Swift:

```
SKRenderer *renderer = [SKRenderer rendererWithDevice:mtlDevice];
```

To tell the renderer what to draw, we associate it with a previously-created scene:

```
renderer.scene = (SKScene *)scene;
```

If you want actions to run, you'll need to manually un-pause the scene, something that is normally done by `SKView` when presenting a scene:

```
scene.paused = NO;
```

To actually draw the scene, we'll need to provide a command buffer and render pass descriptor. Supposing you're using an `MTKView` to handle running the display link timer and manage a `CAMetalLayer`, you can write a delegate method like this, which updates the scene's time (and actions) via the renderer, then draws into the `MTKView`'s drawable:

```
- (void)drawInMTKView:(nonnull MTKView *)view {
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor;
    if (renderPassDescriptor == nil) {
        return;
    }

    [self.renderer updateAtTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [self.commandQueue commandBuffer];
    CGRect viewport = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.drawableSize.width, view.drawableSize.height);
    [self.renderer renderWithViewport:viewport
                        commandBuffer:commandBuffer
                 renderPassDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];

    // TODO: Add any additional Metal rendering here

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
    [commandBuffer commit];
}
```

Remember to set the `MTKView`'s `framebufferOnly` property to `NO` if you use this technique.

If you want to render offscreen into a texture you've created, you'll need to do a bit more manual work, but the concepts involved are the same. You can encode separate passes that render to the same texture by creating additional render pass descriptors/encoders; just remember to set the `loadAction` of the primary color attachment to `MTLLoadActionLoad` to preserve the contents of the texture across passes.

You can also use the `renderWithViewport:renderCommandEncoder:renderPassDescriptor:commandQueue:` to consolidate all drawing into a single pass.

Some caveats:

- As far as I can tell, the `viewport` parameter is ignored.
- If you want the `SKScene` to receive `NSResponder` actions, you'll need to manually forward them or insert the scene into the responder chain. This especially applies to key events, where the scene (or an object responsible for forwarding to it) needs to be *first* responder.
- None of the convenience methods for converting touch or mouse event locations will work when the scene isn't presented by an `SKView`; you'll need to do some manual translation.

Comment: Were you able to make the SKScene "transparent" in a way that you could render layers of textures "behind" the SKScene? EDIT: Actually this is accomplished just by using the `renderWithViewport:renderCommandEncoder:renderPassDescriptor:commandQueue:` as you already mentioned.

Comment: @warrenm how would you  insert the scene into the responder chain?

Comment: Do you have a working sample code project for this solution? thx

Answer (score 1):

swift

```
   func render(renderCommandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder){
    skScene.size = Engine.previewViewSize



        currentTime = 0//allows looping skaction


    //sprite kit render
    skrender.update(atTime: currentTime )

    let viewport = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (Engine.previewViewSize.width), height: (Engine.previewViewSize.height))

    skScene.isPaused = false

    skrender.scene = skScene

    skrender.render(withViewport: viewport, renderCommandEncoder: renderCommandEncoder, renderPassDescriptor: Engine.currentRenderPassDescriptor, commandQueue: Engine.CommandQueue)


}
```